# Build Visual Studio 2003 solution or .NET 1.1 projects with psake

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, psake

Unfortunately, I have mixed .NET version projects. Some legacy code is in .NET 1.1 and other is in .NET 3.5. I cannot use

```
exec { msbuild test.sln }
```

because msbuild does not support compiling .NET 1.1 solution.

How can I build .NET 1.1 solutions with psake? I think psake is cool and want to utilise it.

On command prompt, I can do

```
.\devenv.com /rebuild release "c:\engine.sln"
```

But I can't figure out how I do the same thing within psake build file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If

```
.\devenv.com /rebuild release "c:\engine.sln"
```

is what you do, all you have to do is either make sure devenv is in PATH or supply the full path and do:

```
exec { devenv.com /rebuild release "c:\engine.sln"}
```